# Repeated kernel panic on 2019 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I've been having a very strange problem with my computer. Two to three times a week, and more often recently, the computer becomes unresponsive for a few seconds, then shuts down. I think this is a kernel panic, but I don't get the [normal panic message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9v5A.jpg). I have tried everything from reinstalling the operating system to getting the logic board replaced by Apple. I have no external devices connected like a display or keyboard. System information shows no kernel extensions installed.

Computer details: 2019 MacBook Pro 15" with 2.4 GHz Octa-Core Intel i9, 32 GB RAM, and Radeon Pro 555X. Running macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Panic log was too long to fit, so I put four of them (panic-full-xxxx.ips) [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKlcqUfVvsu286Uj6OK7tfMg9y0Y03II/view?usp=sharing), [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wG4HACrblDYTx-IaK9lkZbp5dMXOj8g3/view?usp=sharing), [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y0hXqb5vD7DI-BVPHYEoSQj_5FLTh2Pz/view?usp=sharing), and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuP3U2PUgSoWDFY9xubMaJYGr-atLszc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I noticed several references to Bridge OS in the logs.  A quick search found many stories, like [here](https://venturebeat.com/2018/07/25/apple-t2-chip-blamed-for-2018-macbook-pro-and-imac-pro-crashes/) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250180853), pointing to a problem with the T2 chip.  I haven't seen a resolution yet but you might want to contact Apple for your repair options.

Comment: Does that mean that it was just chance that the replaced logic board that I got happened to have a faulty chip? If so, I can just ask them to replace it again. I have an appointment with Apple in a few days, but I would like to get it resolved sooner than that, because this is my main computer.

Comment: Sounds frustrating! After scanning the articles posted by @fsb I would try to get Apple to replace the machine with a new one or give you a reduced cost upgrade. The only time I had hardware replaced under Apple Care, I received a refurbished unit because the item I purchased was no longer manufactured. Good Luck!